# Keep hover state till class is swaped

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a meny which appears once a button is clicked. The button has a hover effect. Once the button is clicked the hover state should stay until the menu (or class is toggled) is closed.

fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/s4nk1zev/220/

js:

```
         //open menu
        $('.tablabel').click(function(event){
      $('.tablabel').not(this).next().removeClass("active")
       $(this).next().toggleClass("active")

    });

    //close if menu clicked
    $(".dpd").click(function(e){

    $(this).toggleClass("active")
  })

    //(!DOESNT WORK YET!) close if clicked outside meny (body)
$('html').click(function (e) {
    if (e.target.id == 'mcontainera') {
          $('.dropdowna').removeClass('active');
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mouseenter and mouseleave to put an hover class and then replace in your css `:hover` by `.hover`

```
var $labels = $('.tablabel').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked')
}).mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).addClass('hover')
}).mouseleave(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if(!$this.hasClass('clicked')) $this.removeClass('hover')           
}).click(function(event){
    $(this).next().toggleClass("active")
});

//close if anything  but menu clicked
var $dpd = $(".dpd")
$(document.body).click(function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('.tablabel') ){
        $dpd.removeClass('active');
        $labels.removeClass('clicked hover')
    }
});
```

If you don't want to close other menu just comment this

```
//  $('.tablabel').not(this).next().removeClass("active")
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s4nk1zev/291/

Comment: Hi, i updated here. i have isolated both updates but neither functions. is the css doing something it shouldnt? https://jsfiddle.net/s4nk1zev/268/  thx

Comment: I edited it was mouseenter and mouseleave not mousein and mouseout

Comment: thank you, your amazin,i added the "close other menu if another is clicked. Something stops the hover state staying on....https://jsfiddle.net/s4nk1zev/309/

Comment: Yes, it is because o the css pseudo selector :hover that you have to replace with the class selector, we manually modifiy .hover. https://jsfiddle.net/s4nk1zev/319/

Comment: And to remove the hover when you click on the other https://jsfiddle.net/s4nk1zev/330/

Comment: OK that is smart, understanding this better now, thank you so much. Even more for coming back to help.